# Cannot import csv file in online Jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I have tried with all the existing combinations

Tried the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop')
df=pd.read_csv("CarPrice_Assignment.csv")
```

where i'm trying to import a file using an online jupyter notebook.

> If I give 'r' in os.chdir(r'C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop') it says no
>   Module named seaborn.
>        If I comment import seaborn statement,it shows file not found error.
>           FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>             5 import os
>             6 os.getcwd()
>       ----> 7 os.chdir(r'C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop')
>             8 df=pd.read_csv("CarPrice_Assignment.csv")
>             9 
>        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop'

Comment: Is this Jupyter notebook running in the cloud e.g. Kaggle or Colab? If so the home directory on your local machine isn't available. You'll need to upload the CSV you want to work with.

Comment: This is an online jupyter console and uploading the csv works fine. All I want is to get the data out of csv which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

1:)

> it says no Module named seaborn

You need to install seaborn before you can use it

If you use pip:

```
pip install seaborn
```

Or conda:

```
conda install seaborn
```

2:)

> If I comment import seaborn statement,it shows file not found error.

Simply change

```
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop')
df=pd.read_csv("CarPrice_Assignment.csv")
```

to

```
 df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop\CarPrice_Assignment.csv')
```

If you copy the path (`C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop\CarPrice_Assignment.csv`) into your explorer the csv file should be opened. If it doesn't, your path is wrong.

Comment: I have installed seaborn and restarted the kernel too. Checked by placing C:\Users\mgs2374\Desktop\CarPrice_Assignment.csv in browser. The file is present.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Users\\mgs2374\\Desktop\\LinearRegressionAssignment\\CarPrice_Assignment.csv' does not exist: b'C:\\Users\\mgs2374\\Desktop\\LinearRegressionAssignment\\CarPrice_Assignment.csv'

got the above message.

Does it has anything to do with online jupyter compiler?

Comment: If your jupyter is online your file should be placed on your webserver and the path should point to the destination on your webserver where you placed the file

Comment: Can you provide with steps so that I can try the same?

Comment: use e.g. ftp to upload your file to your webserver and change the path in your jupyter program to the destination you placed the file in. That, of course, supposes that you are able to place files on your webserver.